# Vue js form binding for label and radio button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to produce a list of forms that are polls dynamically from the data. However using :for or v-bind:for doesn't produce any html markup in the browser so the labels aren't selecting the relative input when clicked. I have created a JSFiddle (SCSS wont work in JS Fiddle for some reason). Also the project is a Nuxt build.

Code:
https://jsfiddle.net/mc4rdle/o19bgjpe/2/

Markup:

```
<div class="option" v-for="answer in poll.answers" :key="answer.answer.id">
  <input type="radio" :id="answer.id" :value="answer.answer">
  <label class="option" :for="answer.id">
     <div class="indicator"></div>
     <div class="label">{{ answer.answer }}</div>
   </label>
</div>
```

Data:
polls: [

```
{
                    id: 1,
                    question: 'How do you feel about your current salary?',
                    answers: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            answer: 'Satisfied'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            answer: 'Content'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            answer: 'Unhappy'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    question: 'What group activity should we do??',
                    answers: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            answer: 'Yoga'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            answer: 'Table Tennis'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            answer: 'Pints'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input id is duplicated because it based only on answer's id. You can make it unique by combine both `poll.id + '-' + answer.id`

```
    <div class="option" v-for="answer in poll.answers" :key="answer.answer.id">
      <input type="radio" :id="poll.id + '-' + answer.id" :value="answer.answer" :name="poll.id">
      <label class="option" :for="poll.id + '-' + answer.id">
        <div class="indicator"></div>
        <div class="label">{{ answer.answer }}</div>
      </label>
    </div>
```

Demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ittus/qvpc6t5e/1/)